# SMTP BCC feature in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, bcc

I am looking to add BCC mail feature in the following code. How can I make changes in the following code to send an auto email to more than one email's

```
    Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient()
    Dim Mail As New MailMessage()
    SMTPServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(" ")
    SMTPServer.Port = 587
    SMTPServer.Host = " "

    Mail = New MailMessage
    Mail.From = New MailAddress(" ")


    Mail.To.Add(dr("").ToString)

    Mail.Subject = "Patient Assignment"
    Mail.Body = "   "



    SMTPServer.Send(Mail)
```

Comment: [MailMessage.Bcc Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx)

Comment: Could you let me know, how  will I incorporate this in the existing code.

Comment: Actually I think it will be Mail.BCC.add instead of mail.To.Add

Comment: `Mail.Bcc.Add(New MailAddress(dr("").ToString()))`